# PHPMailer cannot be resolved

Tags: php, phpmailer

So I am trying to set up a contact us page on a website i am creating but PHPMailer just refuses to work for me.

From what I can see, it just isn't recognizing the PHPMailer class at all and I am not really sure why. Here is my PHP code for the form to send the email, as far as i can tell i have correctly installed PHPMailer/Composer, and have done everything else correctly, but i still get errors when trying to use PHPMailer at all. "PHPMailer cannot resolved to a type" and "The import PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer cannot be resolved"

```
    <?php   
                    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
                    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

                    // Bunch of code validating all the variables from the form

                    function send_mail($toEmail, $endSubject, $endMessage, $endName) {                                                  
                        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                        $mail->isSMTP();
                        $mail->Host = "smtp.domain.com";
                        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                        $mail->Username = "LOGIN EMAIL"; // Email
                        $mail->Password = "PASSWORD"; // Email password
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                        $mail->Port = "587";

                        $mail->From = "example@domain.com"; //RANDOM EMAIL TO SEND THESE MESSAGES TO OUR EMAIL
                        $mail->FromName = $endName; //CUSTOMERS NAME

                        $mail->addAddress($toEmail); //WHOEVER WE ARE SENDING THESE EMAILS TO

                        $mail->isHTML(true);

                        $uri = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                        $mail->Subject = $endSubject;
                        $mail->Body = $endMessage;

                        if($mail->send()) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: This sounds like you have not imported the PHPMailer package correctly. What does your `composer.json` file look like?

Comment: Also, you're enabling PHPMailer exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor), but you have no try/catch to catch them.

Comment: {
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0"
    }
}
@Synchro

Comment: Oh right, i completely forgot about the try/catch, i meant to add that and got sidetracked.. will add now.

Comment: Well that's simple enough! If you look in the `vendor` folder, do you see the `PHPMailer` folder with the classes in the `src` folder? These errors look like Eclipse IDE errors rather than PHP errors?

Comment: Yes, i have all of that. They are Eclipse IDE errors, my fault for not making that explicit.

Comment: OK, so this isn't a code question, it's an Eclipse config problem? Does the code run from a command line (outside the IDE) ok? If so, you're probably asking in the wrong place.

Comment: When i try to run it through my server, it just completely bugs out once i click submit and does not send the email either, so i just figured that it was a code problem and those were the only things i saw wrong:/

Comment: Sounds like you could have a PHP problem that's affecting both IDE and CLI. Does PHP run at all?

Comment: Everything not involving the PHPMailer stuff works perfectly. All of the variable validating and such works fine. It just completely breaks when i actually type everything in correctly to send the email off instead of purposely typing things wrong to get the errors.

Comment: If there are errors, they will be in your web server's error log; it won't show up in your browser.

Comment: Not what i meant, like man-made errors, "email format incorrect" stuff like that. Only problem is sending the actual email.

Comment: Which will be failing for some reason, and generating errors, which you need to see. It's unlikely to fail silently. You could try setting `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3` to make it noisier.

Comment: Alright, ill look into it! thanks a lot